Universal commutatization of a ring
Let $R$ be a (not-necessarily-commutative) ring with unity.
Say that ${^{\operatorname{ComRing}\rightarrow}}R \overset{\iota}{\longrightarrow} R$ is universal for morphisms from commutative rings with unity to $R$ if ${^{\operatorname{ComRing}\rightarrow}}R$ is a commutative ring with unity and it fulfills the following universal property:
Given any commutative ring with unity $S$ and a morphism $S \overset{f}{\longrightarrow} R$, there exists a unique $S \overset{\tilde{f}}{\longrightarrow} {^{\operatorname{ComRing}\rightarrow}}R$ such that we have $f = \iota \circ \tilde{f}$.
Say that $R \overset{\pi}{\longrightarrow} R{^{\rightarrow\operatorname{ComRing}}}$ is universal for morphisms from $R$ to commutative rings with unity if $R{^{\rightarrow\operatorname{ComRing}}}$ is a commutative ring with unity and it fulfills the following universal property:
Given any commutative ring with unity $S$ and a morphism $R \overset{f}{\longrightarrow} S$, there exists a unique $R{^{\rightarrow\operatorname{ComRing}}} \overset{\tilde{f}}{\longrightarrow} S$ such that we have $f = \tilde{f} \circ \pi$.

Under what conditions on $R$ does an object ${^{\operatorname{ComRing}\rightarrow}}R$ exist?

Under what conditions on $R$ does an object $R{^{\rightarrow\operatorname{ComRing}}}$ exist?


About question (1.), I have no idea. I suppose that a natural candidate would be the inclusion of the center $Z(R) \overset{\iota}{\longrightarrow} R$, however usually the center is not the largest commutative subring, so this cannot work in all cases, and I don't know any conditions on $R$ that would make it work.
About question (2.), I believe that given a (not-necessarily-commutative) ring with unity $R$, we can take $I = \langle ab-ba \mid a, b \in R \rangle$ to be the ideal generated by the commutators. Now, let $R{^{\rightarrow\operatorname{ComRing}}} = R/I$. Indeed, taking any commutative ring with unity $S$ and any morphism $R \overset{f}{\longrightarrow} S$, we have that $f(ab-ba)=f(a)f(b)-f(b)f(a)=f(a)f(b)-f(a)f(b)=0$, hence $\{ab-ba \mid a, b \in R\} \subseteq \operatorname{ker}(f)$ and since the kernel is an ideal, $I = \langle ab-ba \mid a, b \in R \rangle \subseteq \operatorname{ker}(f)$. Thus, due to the universal property of the quotient ring, $R \overset{f}{\longrightarrow} S$ factors uniquely through a map $R/I \overset{\tilde{f}}{\longrightarrow} S$ with $f = \tilde{f} \circ \pi$.

You are right:
$^{\mathrm{ComRing} \to} R$ does not always exist. If it did, this would give a right adjoint to the inclusion of categories $i : \mathrm{ComRing} \to \mathrm{Ring}$. Then we could conclude that $i$ preserves colimits, but this is false. For example, the coproduct of two copies of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ in $\mathrm{ComRing}$ is $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$, but in $\mathrm{Ring}$ it is $\mathbb{Z}\langle x,y \rangle$ (polynomials in two non-commuting variables).
$R^{\to \mathrm{ComRing}}$ always exists, and is given by exactly the construction you described.

We can show that $^{\mathrm{ComRing} \to} R$ exists if and only if $R$ has a largest commutative subring.
Proof. If $R$ has a largest commutative subring $R_c$, the inclusion $R_c \to R$ clearly is universal.
In the other direction, suppose there is a universal map $\iota : C \to R$ from a commutative ring $C$ to $R$. Let $C'$ denote the image of $\iota$, so that $\iota$ factors as $C \twoheadrightarrow C' \hookrightarrow R$. We verify directly that the inclusion $C' \hookrightarrow R$ is also a universal map from a commutative ring to $R$. Since all commutative subrings of $R$ map to $R$ via inclusions, we find that $C'$ contains all commutative subrings of $R$. Since $C'$ is itself a commutative subring of $R$, we conclude that $C'$ is the largest commutative subring of $R$. $\square$

Furthermore, it turns out that $R$ has a largest commutative subring if and only if $R$ is commutative.
Proof. Let $C$ be the largest commutative subring of a ring $R$. Let $x \in R$ be arbitrary. The subring of $R$ generated by $x$ is commutative, and thus contained in $C$. Thus, $x \in C$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $C = R$, and so $R$ is commutative. Conversely, if $R$ is commutative, then its largest commutative subring is $R$. $\square$

Thanks. Do you know of any ring-theoretic ways to characterize the property of having a largest commutative subring?

Actually it turns out that this happens if and only if the ring itself is commutative! I've edited my answer to include this argument. This happens because any ring generated by a single element is commutative.
